# Mongodb Java driver to execute JS function in query

Tags: java, mongodb

How can I do following with Mongodb Java driver:

```
db.products.insert({
    "id":nextValue("productIdSequence"),
    "product_name":"Apple iPhone",
    "category":"mobiles"
});
```

Following doesn't execute JS stored in server:

```
Document document = toDocument(object);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer().append("nextValue(\'").
        append("productIdSequence").
        append("\')");
BsonJavaScript sequenceFunction = new BsonJavaScript(sb.toString());
document.append("id", sequenceFunction);
database.getCollection("products").insertOne(document);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? This link seems to indicate that it's not even possible: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/HQS0-H2vsb0 You can, however, directly pass in your JavaScript code through the query interface as opposed to running a stored script.

Comment: By the look of it you are actually trying to follow the example of [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) and are taking the "example" too literally. The solution here is **not** "create a JavaScript function" but rather instructs of the usage of the `.findOneAndUpdate()` ( or findAndModify( ) historically ) method for incrementing a value stored in another collection and returning that to use for insertion into another document. The **intent** is to use you **native code** for this, and not just JavaScript.

Comment: Hi. I'm not getting error, but wrong value inside document: "id" : { "code" : "nextValue('productIdSequence')" } should be: "id": 32 for example. Yes, looks like it is not possible, that's actually bad.